# zsh: map command to array

Tags: shell-script, zsh, array

suppose you have an array `a=(foo 'bar baz')`

is there a more obvious way to apply a command/function to every array element and save the resulting strings into another array than this:

```
b=()
for e in $a; do
    b+=("$(my_cmd "$e")")
done
```

Comment: @jimmij: funny that you lowercased the title: I wanted to submit it like that at first, but StackExchange told me “The title does not fullfill quality requirements and grammar”, so I changed it ^^

Answer (score 3):

You can always declare a function for that:

```
map() {
  local arrayname="$1" cmd="$2" i
  shift 2
  eval "$arrayname=()"
  for i do
    eval "$arrayname+=(\"\$($cmd)\")"
  done
}
```

And use as:

```
$ a=(a '' bcd)
$ map b 'wc -c <<< "$i"' "$a[@]"
$ echo $b
2 1 4
```

Comment: if there’s no better builtin, defining my own probably the ideal option. although a signature like `map dest-name source-name cmd and args...`, as well as xargs-like behavior (append as last argument or use `{}` as placeholder) would be better than supplying the command as string and using a magic `$i` variable…

Answer (score 1):

If you know in advance what the command is doing with array elements then you can use *parameter expansion flags* (see `man zshexpn`) to instruct `zsh` how to adapt command output to array.

---

**Example**

Let's say an array `a` contains the names of files, and each file contains only one line of text:

```
$ a=(foo 'bar baz')
$ cat foo
A
$ cat 'bar baz'
B C
```

Now let's assume for argument sake, that the command is just `cat` to put into an array `b` the content of files. In this case instead of loop we can simply write

```
b=(${(f)"$(cat "${a[@]}")"})
```

where `(f)` splits the result of `cat` into separates words at newlines.

The result is as expected:

```
$ echo "${b[1]}"
A
$ echo "${b[2]}"
B C
```

---

According to the real case scenario you can split on different characters with flag `ps:<character>:`. Some of them as newline `(ps:\n:)` from the example above or NULL character `(ps:\0:)` have shorthand: `(f)` and `(0)` respectively.

Comment: A note about that: `${(ps:\0:)"$(cmd)"}` will split on _sequences of NULs_ (if `cmd` outputs `a\0\0b\0`, that will split into `'a'` and `'b'`). You can use `"${(@ps:\0:)"$(cmd)"}"` but then that will split into `'a'`, `''`, `'b'` and `''` which is not what you want either unfortunately if you want to process NUL _delimited_ (as opposed to _separated_) records (also note that command substitution strips all trailing newline characters)

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
eval "b=(" '"$(cmd "$a['{1..$#a}']")"' ")"
```

But that's not very legible.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note:

you can make it shorter with:

```
for e ($a) b+=("$(my_cmd "$e")")
```

Note that `$a` loops over the non-empty elements. To loop over all the elements, it's `"$a[@]"`.